# Expandir - Aumentar archivo adjunto bcp sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Hola buenas estoy realizando un envio de correo desde una sintaxis, pero he notado si el archivo sobrepasa los 8MB no me manda ningun mensaje de error y tampoco no se envia el correo, como podria configurar para que pueda ocupar mas de 8MB
esa es la sintaxis que utilizo y en el log de correo solo tengo esto

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
declare @cmd varchar(8000),@name varchar(100)              
       
select @name='MONITOR_EFECTIVIDADES_'+convert(varchar(8),getdate()-1,112)        
        
set @cmd='del "G:\Spooler\DesarrolloClientes\'+@name+'.csv"'        
EXEC xp_cmdshell @cmd        
        
set @cmd='bcp "select ''COD_TERRITORIO'',''TERRITORIO'',''COD_CORREDOR'',''CORREDOR'',''COD_UNID'',''UNIDAD'',''PRODUCTO'',''COD_SECT'',''SECTORISTA'',''CTA_CLIENTE'',''NOMBRE_CLIENTE'',''OPERACION'',''FEC_DESEMB'',''MONTO_DESEM'',''COD_MONEDA'',''SALDO_CAPITAL_MN'',''TRAMO'',''DIA_ATRAZO'',''HINDZCUO'',''HINDUCUO'',''REG_GESTION'',''NUM_REGISTRO'',''FECHA_GEST'',''HFCRES'',''HFCCOM'',''HFCRSPB'',''PROBAB_RECUP'',''ESTRAT_COBR'',''NIVEL_SOB'',''NIVEL_RIESGO_H'',''HFCMPP'',''HFCFVPP'',''HFGPR'',''HFDGPR'',''FEC_VENCI'',''ESTADO'',''SALDO_INI'',''FEC_MORA'',''MINORISTA'',''REFINANCIADO'',''REPROGRAMADO'',''EXCEPCIONES'',''NUM_CONDO'',''GRUPO'',''TOTAL_CUOTAS'',''CUOTA_PAGADAS'', ''%AVA_CRONOG'',''FEC_VENC_ULT_PAGO'',''PROVINCIA'',''DISTRITO'',''HFCFGEST_RECU'',''HFCRES_RECU'',''HFCCOM_RECU'',''HFCRSPB_RECU'',''HCLFSBS'' '        
set @cmd+=' UNION ALL select cast(RCODTER as varchar) ,cast(RDESTER as varchar) ,cast(RCODCOR as varchar) ,cast(RDESCOR as  varchar) ,cast(RCODUNI as varchar),cast(RDESUNI as varchar) ,cast(RDESPROD as varchar) ,cast(HCODSEC as varchar) ,cast(HDCODSEC as varchar),cast(HCTACLI as varchar) ,cast(HDESCLI as varchar) ,cast(HCODOPE as varchar) ,cast(HFECDES as varchar) ,cast(HMONDES as varchar),cast(HCODMON as varchar) ,cast(HSALCAPMN as varchar) ,cast(HTRAM as varchar) ,cast(HDIAATR as varchar) ,cast(HINDZCUO as varchar),cast(HINDUCUO as varchar) ,cast(HREGG as varchar) ,cast(HREGN as varchar) ,cast(HFCFGEST as varchar) ,cast(HFCRES as varchar),replace(replace(replace(replace(HFCCOM,char(9),'' ''),char(10),'' ''),char(13),'' ''),''-'','' ''),cast(HFCRSPB as varchar) ,cast(HPROBR as varchar) ,cast(HESTC as varchar) ,cast(HNIVSOB as varchar),cast(NIVEL_RIESGO_H as varchar),cast(HFCMPP as varchar) ,cast(HFCFVPP as varchar) ,cast(HFGPR as varchar) ,cast(HFDGPR as varchar) ,cast(HFTVEN as varchar),cast(HESTACT as varchar) ,cast(HSALINIMN as varchar),cast(HFECMOR as varchar),cast(MINORISTA as varchar),CAST(HINDCART AS VARCHAR),CAST(HINDREPR AS VARCHAR),CAST(HINDEXCP AS VARCHAR),CAST(HNUMCOND AS VARCHAR),CAST(HDESGRUP AS VARCHAR),CAST(HTOTCUO AS VARCHAR),CAST(HCUOPAG AS VARCHAR),CAST(AV_CRO AS VARCHAR) ,CAST(HFECUCC AS VARCHAR),CAST(HPROVINCIA AS VARCHAR),CAST(HDISTRITO AS VARCHAR),cast(HFCFGEST_RECU as VARCHAR),CAST(HFCRES_RECU AS VARCHAR),CAST(HFCCOM_RECU AS VARCHAR),CAST(HFCRSPB_RECU AS VARCHAR),CAST(HCLFSBS AS VARCHAR)  from storage.[com_act].WCED002__"'         
set @cmd+=' queryout  "G:\Spooler\DesarrolloClientes\'+@name+'.csv" -b"1000" -c -t\t -T -r"\n" -S NUM_SERV -U  master -P CLAVE -C1252'        
--print @cmd        
EXEC xp_cmdshell @cmd        
        
set @cmd='7z a -tzip "G:\Spooler\DesarrolloClientes\'+@name+'.csv.zip" ""G:\Spooler\DesarrolloClientes\'+@name+'.csv"';         
EXEC xp_cmdshell @cmd        
        
set @cmd='del "G:\Spooler\DesarrolloClientes\'+@name+'.csv"'        
EXEC xp_cmdshell @cmd        
        
 declare @subj varchar(max),@HTML varchar(max),@recip varchar(100),@attach varchar(max)          
 select @subj='Monitor de Efectividades '+cast(cast(getdate()-1 as date) as varchar(10))+''          

 select @HTML=N'           
 <p>Buenos días.</p></br>           
          
 <p>Se remite el monitor de efectividades.</p>          
          
 <p>Un cordial saludo,</p></br>          
 <p>MIS</p>          
 '          
 select @attach='G:\Spooler\DesarrolloClientes\MONITOR_EFECTIVIDADES_'+convert(varchar(8),getdate()-1,112)+'.csv.zip'        
            
 EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail   
 @recipients='pierro@gmail.com',   
 
 @subject =  @subj,          
 @body = @HTML,           
 @body_format = 'HTML',           
 @profile_name = 'Google Mail - MIS',          
 @file_attachments = @attach;
```

Answer (score 0):

En el Object Explorer, en la carpeta `"Management"`. Abra el asistente de configuración `"Database Mail"`.

Haga clic en Siguiente -> Elija el botón de opción `"View of change system parameters"` y haga clic en Siguiente.

Ahora cambie la propiedad `"Maximum File Size (Bytes)"` y haga clic en Siguiente, luego haga clic en Finalizar para guardar los cambios.

Respuesta sacada de esta [pregunta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/997628/how-do-i-increase-the-maximum-allowed-attachment-size-for-email-sent-using-msdb) que fue tomada como buena, espero te sirva.

Comment: lo modifique hasta 12 MB pero igual :(

Comment: @PieroDev Lamento que no te sirviera :( aunque en la misma pregunta y en otros lados he visto este query o uno parecido `EXECUTE msdb.dbo.sysmail_configure_sp 'MaxFileSize', '10000000';`

Comment: si justo eso he colocado pero no se porque igual le he mucho mayor pero igual mas bien te agradezco mucho por tu tiempo valoro mucho

Comment: Lamento que no te funcionará :(